# get image frames webcam from server with selenium python script

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to take image frames from a **webcam server** using selenium python module.

The frames webcam is show on the selenium browser ( using http:// .....html webpage) .

The source code of the page show me it's done using some java script.

I try to use:

`capture_network_traffic() and captureNetworkTraffic`

Not working , also I don't think is a good way to do that.
Also I don't want to use capture_screenshot functions , this take all canvas of the browser.

Any idea ?
Thank you. Regards.

Comment: Would it be possible to show us your webpage so that we can have a better idea of what you are trying to extract?

Comment: The source page of the html i try to using it's something like : <html> ...<script language="JavaScript" src="http://..../webcam.js.php?id=111" type="text/javascript"></script></html> ... this script show one image in the  webbrowser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, what you'll need to do is navigate to the webpage with Selenium.

Then, analyse the web page source HTML which the Javascript will have rendered by you navigating to the page, to get the image URL. You can do this with Selenium or with an HTML parser.

Then you can easily download the image using `wget` or some other URL grabber.

You might not even need Selenium to accomplish this if when you get the page, the image is already there. If that is the case you can just use the URL grabber to get the page directly.

Let me know if you want more details or if you have any questions.

Comment: the problem is the image is change based on some random and time . the script has some next_image ... the source html not have a source image point one image but the image from html is created and changed in time by java script very fast.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't totally understand your problem with my answer. Can you find the image link in the HTML when examining the page source?

Comment: http://www.aficotroceni.ro/webcams/starbucks.html?iframe=false see the java script and html source and will understand. I need to parse the images with OpenCv this is the main reason.

Comment: If you left click on the image in Chrome and display the source code, you will see that the image has a source URL. Something like:
http://www.live-events.ro/cam-acces-privat-delay.php?i=89&counter=1374573012185
Usually, it would be as easy and downloading that image directly from that URL, but for some reason, the website won't allow that. Consequently, I'm out of my depth as to what to do here. You're probably going to need a messy work-around, like grabbing screenshots every time the page updates. But maybe if you Google "grabbing images with Selenium" you will be enlightened?

Comment: Thnak you for your comments. As you see is not very easy to take some data because image is dinamically change. :) The goal of this issue is  how selenium can deal with that. About "the website won't allow that."  and your answer about wget then wget can also simulated some browsers. Have selenium something new and low level to deal with something this ?

Comment: The fact that the page is dynamic is not a problem. Selenium can inform you when the pages updates by checking the page for an element. The problem is grabbing the image. Did you Google as I suggested?

Comment: I also suggest you Google wget and that you try grabbing some images off the internet with their src URL to understand what I'm talking about.